# How do I include library files in ImHex's Pattern Language?

Tags: imhex-pattern-language

I'm just beginning to use ImHex's *Pattern Language*, so forgive me that this question is extremely basic.

I want to read data from the loaded file into my script written in *Pattern Language*.  In the documentation, there is a built-in library, `hex/core`, which appears to have the desired functionality.

However, if I try to include this library like this:
 `#include <hex/core>`
I get the following error:

```
E: error[M0004]: No such file or directory
E:   --> <Source Code>:2:1
E: 2 | #include <hex/core>
E:     ^
E:     Path doesn't point to a valid file.
```

[The documentation's](https://docs.werwolv.net/pattern-language/) description of the `#include` directive shows an example being loaded with the `.hexpat` extension, but that gives the same error.

Given that the language is  "C++ and Rust-inspired," I tried `#include <hex/core.h>`, but again received the exact same error.

How do I include built-in libraries in *Pattern Language*?

Comment: I wanted to add a new tag, [imhex-pattern-language], but I do not have enough rep.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/imhex-pattern-language/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `.pat` extension for built-in libraries.

---

I discovered the answer in the [documentation for ImHex](https://docs.werwolv.net/imhex/views/pattern-editor) - not *Pattern Language*.  Under its section on the Pattern Editor, I noticed this line in the sample code:

```
#include <std/string.pat>
```

Adding the `.pat` extension in my code fixed the problem.